# Range over alias of slice of pointers

Tags: go

I have the following structure (where Vector3 is a custom struct)

```
type Polygon []*Vector3
```

How do i iterate (using range) over the underlying slice with Vector3 of Polygon?

Example:

```
func (p *Polygon) print() {
    for _, v := range p { // not allowed!! :(
       // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: `p` is a pointer, dereference first and then iterate. e.g. `for ... := range *p { ...`.

Comment: alternatively you could declare the method on a non-pointer receiver type, i.e. `func (p Polygon) print() {...` then you don't have to dereference and your original attempt will work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not range over a pointer. Here `p` is `*Polygon` means pointer of type `Polygon`. So, dereferencing the pointer to range over.

`*` is used to `dereference` pointer variables.

```
func (p *Polygon) print() {
    for _, v := range *p {
        // do something
    }
}
```